# Unlock GSM iPhone 4?

Tags: iphone, sim, cdma

Can I unlock a GSM iPhone 4 so that I can use a CDMA SIM card and make calls using the CDMA card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is no...    the GSM phones cannot work on the CDMA networks, even when changing SIM cards.   The hardware is actually slightly different.

If you have a GSM iPhone, you'll only be able to unlock it and move it between cell companies using GSM.

[This article](https://www.puretalkusa.com/blog/whats-the-deal-with-unlocked-phones/) gives some additional info on the topic...